# Oracle Database Login Error

Tags: java, database, oracle

I am trying to install JDA Platform. I have installed all pre-requisite applications and when I run **runpostinstalltask** command through cmd after providing all relevant passwords to create database users and schema, I am getting an error "ORA-01017 invalid username/password" and system logs me out from Oracle and hence I am not able to create any user/schema and unable to proceed other applications.

Any thoughts how to resolve it..

Comment: Can you verify that the user you're trying to login as actually exists?